# Why did some devices have custom USB cable ends in the 2000's

Tags: usb, connector

I recently bought a used USB dock for upgrading firmware on a camera lens, only to notice the USB connector was custom.

Thinking about it, I also had a few devices like cheap cameras, calculators etc. in the 2000's and 2010's that used slightly altered ends to replace a "mini" sized USB connector.

Could this have been done to avoid royalties etc? None of the systems I am thinking of had special needs etc. Other than they were typically cheap, but a $1000 camera lens from that era does not fit the 'cheap' definition.

Below is the sigma USB cable I just got, it has a 45* cut across the USB face, and the pins are not in a consistent pitch spacing.

[image]

Comment: If the device only supports USB low speed (like most keyboards and mice), then it must either have a permanently attached cable or a custom plug. It would be interesting to know if this applies to those cheap devices.

Comment: Can you get a photo that shows the actual features you're talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Vendor lock-in. If you had a Nokia phone and your charger cable broke, you would need to buy a new one from Nokia. If you had a Blackberry phone and your charger cable broke, you would need to buy a new one from Blackberry. At least that was the idea; it wasn't long before you could buy third-party cables made for specific devices, if those devices were popular enough.

The only reason this isn't *still* the case is that it's now illegal; there's an industry standard (that I believe has legal weight behind it in the EU) that requires everything (in certain classes of device, anyway) to use either micro-USB or USB type C. For some reason Apple has managed to secure an exception to this, so they still have their own connectors.

Comment: Can you give a link to or more detail about this EU standard / regulation? I'd like to learn more about it. Thanks!

Comment: @TypeIA I feel like there was some level of regulation before this, but there was a recent ruling ([random news article about it](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-58665809)) that will mandate USB-C for all phones in the EU. Apparently Apple didn't manage to worm their way out of this one, so they're pretty upset.

Comment: @TypeIA Ah, here's the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_external_power_supply) about the previous standard, implemented in 2009. That one was voluntary, but most companies followed it (except apple). The new one looks like it'll be mandatory.

Comment: Thanks. That article describes a _proposal_ though, not a _ruling_. (That's not immediately clear from the somewhat misleading headline.) I'll keep reading more about this, thanks again.

Comment: @TypeIA And [here's](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/electrical-and-electronic-engineering-industries-eei/radio-equipment-directive-red/one-common-charging-solution-all_en) some info from an official EU source about the new standard.

Comment: @TypeIA The last link I just posted says that the "proposal [...] was adopted by the College" on september 23rd; I'm not sure what exactly that means in the process of it becoming official, since I'm not an EU citizen and have little knowledge of the EU legislative process.

Comment: FWIW, Blackberries used standard Mini-USB connectors.  Either hard-wired to the power supply or using full-size A connectors.

Comment: @AlexHajnal I never had a blackberry, and it was just the first 2000s phone maker that came to mind after Nokia. Do you have any others that had weird connectors?

Answer (score 3):

In the late 90s there wasn’t a workable USB device connector for phones. The full-size USB type B connector was far too bulky to be practical on the then-emergent class of mobile devices, let alone mice. It was really only useful for hubs.

Instead, mobile phone manufacturers did their own more-compact device end connectors, if they used USB at all. So that’s why connector chaos reigned in the early days, not necessarily an intentional vendor lock-in (although there was no doubt some of that going on too.)

The USB Organization took notice, and developed the Mini-B and Micro-B, both introduced with USB2.0 (c.2000). Mini-B saw some use (notably on the Motorola RAZR) with Micro-B ultimately becoming the standard for smartphones (Apple notwithstanding), even finally mandatory in the EU.

Perhaps more important than the small connector, USB 2.0 brought a speed boost to 480Mbps, making it more useful for transferring photos and music. This sweetened the deal for phone makers to adopt it. On-the-Go was in there too, but it proved troublesome to implement fully.

Meanwhile, Apple used the iPod dock connector in the first iPhones, a hideous choice from day one. The Lightning cable that replaced it from iPhone4 forward was a huge improvement. As a phone connector I still consider it superior to both Micro-B or USB-C based on it being simpler and more rugged, while offering high throughput.